# Confusion regarding work done by external force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, work, potential-energy

Suppose a ball from outer space is moving towards earth. The force of gravity attracts the ball more and more strongly as it moves closer and closer to the earth. Now, let me apply an external force on the ball in the midst of it's journey which is equal and opposite to the force of gravity. Since, the net force on the ball is zero, it will still continue moving towards the earth, but this time with a constant velocity. So the change in kinetic energy of the ball as it keeps moving closer and closer to earth is zero in the presence of the external force. But the change in potential energy of the ball is not zero. It goes on decreasing with decreasing distance from the earth. If there was no external force present, then this decrease in potential energy accounts for the increase in kinetic energy of the ball. My question is, how shall we explain this decrease in potential energy when an external force is present?

Comment: What’s the issue? Are you asking how energy is conserved?

Comment: @cms yes, how energy is conserved

Comment: Energy _is not_ conserved when an external force is present, as the external force applies power equal to $P=F\,v$ to the system.

Answer (score 2):

> Now, let me apply an external force on the ball in the midst of its
> journey which is equal and opposite to the force of gravity.

First of all, the external force you need to apply has to keep increasing as the ball moves closer to the earth, in order for the net force and net work done on the ball to be zero, since the force of gravity keeps increasing. In other words, your external force cannot be constant if the velocity of the ball and its kinetic energy is to be constant.

> My question is, how shall we explain this decrease in potential energy
> when an external force is present?

With no external force, the positive work done by gravity would cause an increase in kinetic energy of the ball equal to the decrease in gravitational potential energy of the ball-earth system. With the external force the agent performing the negative work on the ball takes away the increase in kinetic energy the ball would have been given due to the positive work of gravity.

*Bottom line: The gravitational potential energy keeps decreasing because gravity is doing positive work at the expense of gravitational potential energy. But the kinetic energy of the ball does not increase due to the equal amount of negative work simultaneously being done by the external force.*

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your confusion is because you have failed to realise that you have considered two different systems.

**System ball alone**
*So the change in kinetic energy of the ball as it keeps moving closer and closer to earth is zero in the presence of the external force.* should state that there are **two** external forces acting on the ball which are equal in magnitude and opposite in direction, the force of gravitational attraction on the ball due to the Earth and the *let me apply an external force on the ball*.
No net work is done on the ball and so its kinetic energy does not change.

**System ball and Earth**
*But the change in potential energy of the ball is not zero.*
The ball alone cannot have gravitational potential energy as there must be at least one other mass present which in this case is the Earth.
There is one external force acting, the *let me apply an external force on the ball*.
Work is done by the system which can be interpreted as  negative work done by your external force, and the gravitational potential energy of the **system** decreases.

Answer (score 1):

You start from the wrong premise. The change in potential energy is not "explained" by a change in KE.  It is due to and explained by the work done by the gravitational force. This work is the same for the same gravitational force, irrespective of what any other force is doing. Only the change in KE depends on the net force, so all the forces acting on the object, including what you call "external force".
So the two situations are different because the net force is different. This explains why the change in KE is different: positive in the first case and zero in the second. The gravitational force is the same in both cases so the change in PE is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider the work of your external force, it will be negative (because the displacement and force are orientated in opposite sides), so it will mean that source of external force will gain energy from ball. For example, imagine if ball is a water molecule and external force is the turbine at electric station. The pressure of column of water will generate electricity by forcing turbine to make negative work or in other terms (turbine presses on the water against the gravity direction), the ball is making a positive work on source of external force and because of this the source is obtaining energy.